# UPDATE SQL Command not saving the results

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

I looked though the forum but I couldn't find a issue like mine.

Essentially I have a table called [p005_MMAT].[dbo].[Storage_Max]. It has three columns Date, HistValue and Tag_ID. I want to make all the values in 'HistValue' column to have 2 decimal places. For example if a number is 1.1, I want it to be 1.10 or if its 1 then also I want it to look like 1.00.

Here is the sql update statement I am using

```
update [p005_MMAT].[dbo].[Storage_Max]
set [HistValue] = cast([HistValue] as decimal (10,2))
where [Tag_ID] = 94
```

After executing the query it says 3339 rows affected but when I perform a simple select statement it appears the column had no affect of. I have used that cast function in select statement and it adds two decimal places.

Please advice.

Comment: what is the data type for `HistValue`

Comment: The datatype of HistValue is real

Comment: you are not changing the value at all with that statement. You simply cast `histvalue` to a decimal then assign that (identical) value back to `histvalue` which will convert it back to a float (with still the same value)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the datatype and SQL Server. Float or real will not have the trailing zeros. You either have to change the datatype of the column or just deal with it and handle the formatting in your queries or application.

You could run something like the following

```
select  
  cast([HistValue] as decimal (10,2))
from [p005_MMAT].[dbo].[Storage_Max]
where [Tag_ID] = 94
```

Comment: Thaanks for your response @SQLChao. If I understand this correctly, say if I have a value in [HistValue] column as 13.6 so by running the above mentioned cast syntax will not change the number to 13.6 unless a run an independent sql query.

Comment: @FaisalShibli That is correct because the data type of your column will not have the trailing zeros. I guess the better question is why you need to update the table versus just formatting the data in your query. See my example

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That is what I tried first. Unfortunately the third party application where I am running this sql query is not add trailing zeros. This is because the global application numbering system does not allow trailing 0's. Example a number like 0.01 will be presented as 0.01 however a number 3.60 will be shown as 3.6 or a number like 1.0 will be shown as 1. Hence, I thought to perhaps update the main database and see how the app reads it. I will check out your examples. Thanks again!